# Carrierwave upload image without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, file-upload, carrierwave

How can I use Carrierwave rails gem to upload an image to Amazon S3 without model? Almost all examples I saw used a model, like this:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

and then used form_for to attach image manually:

```
  <%= form_for @gallery do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    ...
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

In my case I just need to upload an image (which I am getting from Google static map) to Amazon S3 and then return it URL without using model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like this?

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
end

uploader = MyUploader.new
uploader.store!(my_file)
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need.
Thanks!